# Want to embed a const char *const template parameter in a struct for use as template parameter in another function

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I want to "embed" a `const char *const` in a struct.

```
  template <const char *const CharArray>
  struct ModName {
    static constexpr int index = Index<S<CharArray>, Tuple>::value;
    static constexpr const char *const name = CharArray; // <--- this is causing me trouble
    using Type = typename ModIndex<index, typename T<index + 1>::Type>::Type;
    using TypePtr = std::unique_ptr<Type>;
  };
```

`index`, `Type` and `TypePtr` all work fine in the context I want to use... but I would also like to use `name` as a template parameter in another templated function, like this:

```
  template <const char *const CharArray,
            class ModDef = ModName<CharArray>>
  typename ModDef::TypePtr BuildModule() {
    return Builder<ModDef>::Build();
  }

  template <class ModDef>
  struct Builder {
    static typename ModDef::TypePtr Build() {
          CheckIfAlreadyBuilt<ModDef::name>(false); // <--- Here I'm getting compilation error
    }
  };

  template <const char *const CharArray>
  static void CheckIfAlreadyBuilt(bool status) {
    ...
  }
```

**Error:** `’...::name’ is not a valid template argument because ‘...::name’ is a variable, not the address of a variable`

Now, I know I could just propagate the original `CharArray` as is in the templated struct `Builder` and solve this, but I want to know if there's a more "elegant" solution and "embed" everything I want in `ModName`. I already tried various stuff like

`... static constexpr char[] name = CharArray;`

but I get different compilation errors

Comment: Can you pass the whole class ModDef as the template parameter to CheckIfAlreadyBuilt?

Comment: Well... yes, I supposed I _could_ , but then I would be passing a lot more information to `CheckIfAlreadyBuilt` than required

Comment: Could you add the code for `CheckIfAlreadyBuilt` to your question?

Comment: I just added it :-)

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. What standard version and compiler are you using?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0 - C++14